# add a button(which is used to activate another app) on win 10 toast

Tags: c++, button, toast, canactivate

I'm looking for methods to add a button on win 10 toast.

I've already made a exe file which is able to call the toast every time I launch it.

But I have no idea how to add a button on my toast(any API in MSDN(C++)?) and the button is able to activate another application.

platforms are: win10, C++, MSDN 2015

thanks!!!

Comment: See [Toast content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#buttons).

Comment: @VTT Thanks for reply! I've read it before but it's programmed in C#. My project is in C++.

Comment: It would be the same with C++. *"The toast content is defined in raw XML, but you can use our NuGet library to get a C# (or C++) object model for constructing the toast content."*